# Makes Firefox to show all hidden history entries?

Tags: windows, firefox

I'm cleaning up my Firefox history and I realize that even though some URLs are not listed in the History panel (by pressing *Ctrl + Shift + H* or go to *History -> Show All History*), they are still showed up when I type something into the Location bar .

I use the [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/?src=ss) addons to open the *places.sqlite* file inside the browser profile folder. I see that in the *moz-places* table there is column name **hidden** and these URLs have this value equal to **1**. When I change this value to **0**, these URLs shows up in the History panel as usual.

So can anybody tell me how to make Firefox not to hide any URLs in its history by default? I'm using Windows 7 and Firefox 18.